# twisted soap raises exception

Tags: python, ubuntu, soap, twisted

using

```
from twisted.web import soap, xmlrpc, resource, server
import os

def getQuote():
    return "Victory to the burgeois, you capitalist swine!"

class XMLRPCQuoter(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    def xmlrpc_quote(self):
        return getQuote()

class SOAPQuoter(soap.SOAPPublisher):
    def soap_quote(self):
        return getQuote()

def main():
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    root = resource.Resource()
    root.putChild('RPC2', XMLRPCQuoter())
    root.putChild('SOAP', SOAPQuoter())
    reactor.listenTCP(7080, server.Site(root))
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get ": :1:0: no element found". Looking into traceback I can see that exception raises when this call were made

```
p, header, body, attrs = SOAPpy.parseSOAPRPC(data, 1, 1, 1)
```

I also tested another twisteSOAP program, I think that's there's some versioning problem.
I'm on a ubuntu 12.04, with twisted 11.01.

probably is some version related to python and xml.
Anyone got something similar ?

if I add, into /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web/soap.py, the following code, at line 52

```
    f = open('/tmp/nannata', 'w')
    f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

looking into /tmp/nannata I can seee that file is void !
So parsing problem, probably, referred to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all this commotion,

using a pure soapclient instead of a web browser runs the games.
So, it was a false-positive.

Is there some suggestion to develop a SOAP server with twisted and ZSI or twised and suds ?
I'll apreciate it a lot :)